# SSRS Subreport Inside a Table Cell not Retrieving Parameters Properly?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I have an SSRS Report using a Table.
You can select multiple Clients and Periods and for every pair there will be a row in the table. So 2 Clients * 3 Periods = 6 rows.

Now... there are some cells that are more complicated than having a single value and I want to place a subreport inside these cells. The Subreport will take the Client and Period for that particular Row as params.

This is where the issue comes in. The Parameters will not pass properly.

I can put Parameters!ClientID.Value(0) as an expression for example and it will pass the first ClientID properly but if I just put Parameters!ClientID.Value it breaks... And I want the Client/Period for the current row.

But how is it that I can't pass the params but CAN fill a new dataset for every row based on that Client/Period pair??

Note that I'd really prefer not to have to edit the SP that builds that dataset to return the Client/Period itself. Sure that would work.. but WHY would that be needed when I have the Parameters?

Any ideas? I'm doing this in a Visual Studio Report Project.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly you don't need to use the parameter. You need to use the value of the field from the dataset. So if your table shows client and period then the parameter values passed in would be `=Fields!Client.Value` and `=Fields!Period.Value`

```
Client    Period    SubReportCell
Bob       2017      "subreport here passing in Bob, 2017"
Geoff     2015      "sub report here passing in Geoff, 2015"
```

You should just be able to choose these from the dropdown lists in the subreport setting dialogue box.

Comment: The ClientID and PeriodID are selected from Drop Downs. They are the Report parameters.
Then there is a SP that takes these values for every row as parameters and returns the DataSet I use for that row.
The DataSet does not contain the IDs within itself.
Then there is a subreport inside every row that I also want to take these parameters.

Comment: You have made me realize that the SP that builds the DataSet takes the LIST of the parameters. I thought it went row by row.... I think I will have to add the values to the dataset.

Comment: OK, I didn't realise you were doing that but hopefully it's got you thinking along a slightly different approach that should make things easier in the long run.